# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never' when dynamically setting an object property with different types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function to update a property on an object that will first cast it from a string to an appropriate scalar type and then dynamically assigns based on the property name passed into it.

This dynamic property access seems to need more precise typing that I can come up with when trying to port my code to TypeScript.

The example below results in two TS errors for  `settings[setting] = value;`:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

([TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKBlBUoCWYA5hDALwwDeAUDDEVAAoBOIADgFwwCMADABo6MaCyLFWHbgHIUAI2DShAXwDcNGlACe7BDFz5xZStt0gk8ZOiwHCJCOoD0jmKb22jANRQY0ekzoI5paomDh4dqQA2gDWCFrBbsGIoTYRRgC6NKCQsBDp9hQh1uGG9uo0SGhgwITgMGjscChQCB4kABTC+WXE3HEJFkkWPZEQQvSi3KLiEyIFxAAqgTKMCMQILNIwAD4w0jMk0jQAlNTCBBYdAIQdo+K7e-ckDGDFYe2kJ2cseGgsYHU9EuMBuokeIigLAAdBgECQoAALCjkSh8H5-AEVehw2AANx8fm4w3mvQgsXiiUCwWepAy2IYV1py10KMo0jWGy2ZwJvn8MHYKBY+QAkmAoHcoQJeOigTAEBh8jBeX4iqIGbTybSMkUVQh1MoNM5XIiCGQza88SA4nAYEg2ABbGAoGAAYQAMiKYAAlACiTHdJpaMA2UDILsOxGdYFtPXDpMiMDkKHytvqwBTiaRCCdUBAzpEuiQBGAJZEGYwQtcgQgNGN+T0IDExCIPhgAClsM7YIj8OwIJxnC2kWg5NDQA7HAArCDARFof6OOctYjsKAAWl+7AwjjkGBAcl3AHYACzAJDAOBHgCsSCPqD4AA4AEwIE+PuA8ABsyYAzDwjy-ABOBA+D4L8jx4E8jxvFBHAgFhgHghYIGhGcAGJ3V-E86xcFAYxgXsoH7QdHGHecxwnadZ3nRdlygVcNy3Hc9wPY8zwvK9b3vFAn1fd9Px-FB-0AkCwIgqCYOvOCEKQicHXwuBUIw91HyPGhGmaVpPg6DlxUkdglH2Z8+CMvTWi5aQTnUHIIBAOFYRAYg7hQ6ygA))

```js
const defaultSettings = {
  intProp: 10,
  stringProp: 'abc',
};

type Settings = typeof defaultSettings;
// type SettingsValue = typeof defaultSettings[keyof typeof defaultSettings]
const settings = defaultSettings;

function updateSetting(
  setting: keyof typeof settings,
  str: string,
  type: 'integer' | 'string'
) {
  if (!(setting || setting in defaultSettings)) return;
  if (!str || str.length === 0) return;

  let value: typeof settings[keyof typeof settings];

  if (type === 'integer') value = parseInt(str, 10);
  else value = str;

  // TS error here
  settings[setting] = value;
}

updateSetting('intProp', '20', 'integer');
console.log(settings);
```

For context, this is a simplified to reproduce the bug. A [more complex `updateSettings`](https://github.com/jschuur/chatgpt-repl/blob/b74cfcd75f7fa082e48d16ba31769e006714775a/src/settings.js#L34) (original JS) takes in a string from a [CLI REPL command](https://github.com/jschuur/chatgpt-repl/blob/b74cfcd75f7fa082e48d16ba31769e006714775a/src/commands.js#L87) and casts the value to a scalar type based on the settings property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the type of `value` and `setting`:

```
setting -> "intProp" | "stringProp"

value -> number | string
```

As you can see, with just

```
settings[setting] = value;
```

TypeScript raise an error because `setting` could be `"stringProp"` while `value` could be a `number` (or `setting` is `intProp` while `value` is `string`).

To fix your issue, you have to determine the type of each union with something like:

```
if(setting === "intProp" && typeof value === "number") {
  settings[setting] = value;
} else if(setting === "stringProp" && typeof value === "string") {
  settings[setting] = value;
}
```

Comment: That narrows (heh) the problem down, thanks. I need more complicated type guards, because I have to distinguish the difference between an integer and a float (and not just typeof 'number'), but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually, since we're just going this to keep TypeScript happy, I think a typeof 'number' check should do fine as a guard.

Comment: @JoostSchuur remember that TS (and JS as well) _does not_ have the concept of `int` and `float` (or `double`) but just `number`